# How to use v-slot:activator and v-on with child component?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have some problems with my Vue.js Project.

Parent Component:

```
<v-menu>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <more-actions :ref="'moreActions' v-on="on" />
          </template>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item @click="handleClick()">
              <v-list-item-title>
                Sample
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

MoreActions Component

```
<template>
  <v-tooltip bottom>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <v-btn icon v-on="on" @click="$emit('click', $event)">
        <v-icon small>
          more_vert
        </v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </template>
    <span>More Actions</span>
  </v-tooltip>
</template>
```

This code is running well(under Vuetify v2.1.9), but doesn't run in Vuetify v2.1.15
(The menu is opend the top left corner.)

How can I fix this?

Here is running code in v2.1.15

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-menu>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on: menu }">
        <v-tooltip bottom>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on: tooltip }">
            <v-btn icon v-on="{ ...tooltip, ...menu }" @click="$emit('click', $event)">
              <v-icon small>
                more_vert
              </v-icon>
            <v-btn>
          </template>
          <span>Im A ToolTip</span>
        </v-tooltip>
      </template>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item @click="handleClick()">
              <v-list-item-title>
                Sample
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
    </v-menu>
  </div>
</template>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please share a codepen that reproduces the issue. That way people can fix your code and help you out.

Answer (score 0):

move this part to the parent component.
and using `<slot />` instead of this part in Child Component.

```
<v-list>
    <v-list-item @click="handleClick()">
        <v-list-item-title>
            Sample
        </v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```